# How to use the code of two DLLs from a third one in C?

Tags: c, dll, compilation

I have two dll's a.dll and b.dll along with their library files a.lib and b.lib. I am trying to write a third dll that has functions that has to make use of functions in a.dll and b.dll.

Is this possible at all?

The output has to be a dll in itself - that is an absolute requirement.

I have the full C source code.

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, then your question title is highly misleading. Do you want to write a DLL that uses two other DLLs, or do you want to use the two existing DLLs in a way that will produce a third DLL? (I assume you meant the former, but your title suggests the latter.)

Comment: The former. I want to write a dll that uses functions provided by two other existing dlls.

Answer (score 0):

'Is this possible at all?'

In short, yes.  DLLs can contain references to other DLLs in the same way that EXEs can.  You don't say what compiler is being used, but it's likely that the 'lib' contains library references to the DLL.  So, you would need to add these libraries into the linker configuration for your new DLL.

You'd typically reference any function prototypes from the other DLLs, via their header files (although you could prototype them again this seems unnecessary since you say you have the code), again this is the same as if you were using the DLL from an EXE.

You'd need to make sure all three DLLs are deployed together, since the new DLL references the existing ones, it does not take a copy of the functions into itself.